# Is it possible to buy unlimited 3G/4G internet in Italy?

Tags: italy, internet

I'm going to rent house in Italy for several months. I do plan to work there so I need a lot of internet every day. I will probably spent 10 Giga every day or even more. But ~70% of the houses in Italy that i'm considering to rent doesn't have wire internet.

I just wonder if it's possible to buy such ammount of traffic wirelessly and how much does it cost? Could someone suggest the best provider? I've checked [TIM](http://www.tim.it/internet/offerte-internet-con-chiavetta-inclusa/internet-42-2-special-edition) for example but it has 10 Gb per month limit and i will spent this limit almost instantly.

Could someone suggest really no limit 3G/4G internet? Otherwise I have to look only for wire-internet houses.

Comment: I would highly discourage using 3G as a solution. Make the wire-internet a requirement for the house you rent, or investigate the possibilities to obtain wired internet.

Comment: If you're looking at 10 gigabytes per day throughput you will need a channel that is capable of sustaining 1.25Mbp/s throughout the day 3G isn't going to do it for you and I really have to question what exactly you're planning to do while traveling to necessitate such network capacity

Comment: I agree with other people commenting, it is very unlikely 3G will be able to provide you with the bandwidth you are after. Especially indoors.

Comment: i just plan to trade on stock exchange, terminal itself requires at least 512 kbit per second. I guess it would be fine for me to have 512kbit per second speed, but this is minimum.

Comment: @Karlson 1 GBit / hour = 1000 Mbit / hour = 16 MBit / minute = 266 KBit / second

Comment: @javapowered That's not what you've written.  10GB/day = 10000000000 / (24*3600) = 115 kB/s ~ 1.15Mbps (not even considering the actual definition of GB).  The only thing is your usage will come between 8:30 - 5:00 local time depending on the exchanges you will trade.  The problem with market data is that it comes in bursts so you will need to have ability to generate peak usage of closer to 5Mbps or more.  This will require a hard line.  And if you are using a Bloomberg Terminal possibly even more.

Comment: @Karlson i need to monitor market data only so it's ok to lag when "peak" occurs. BTW here in Russia I can buy 4G wireless 100 MBit/second NO LIMIT internet just for 40 euro per months here http://www.yota.ru/, looking for something similar in Italy..

Comment: check this out http://www.tre.it/tariffe/tre-dati-plus 1GB/day + 0.20 € per extra 100MB. Only on Tre network coverage tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any carrier here that offers the kind of service you need. Most of them have an "unlimited" traffic options but after a certain threshold of GBs what happens is that you can still navigate the web but with a MUCH slower speed.

Your best bet is to subscribe for ADSL and then unsubscribe it before leaving but you have to be VERY careful because you may need to unsubscribe with some kind of forewarning.

The most important carriers in Italy are:

[TIM](http://www.tim.it)

[TRE](http://www.tre.it)

[VODAFONE](http://www.vodafone.it)

[WIND](http://www.wind.it/it/privati/)

Comment: then the question is - which carrier has the highest speed after threshold is reached.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are all the same, which means: 32 Kbps. Enjoy!

Comment: so far it seems i can buy maximum of 15 GB of internet for 34 euro. why TIM doesn't offer unlimited 4G?.. http://www.tim.it/internet/offerte-internet-con-chiavetta-inclusa/tutto-internet-4g

Comment: 4G isn't common here at all. 3G/4G are mainly used for phone plans or really casual internet surfers. If you need a reliable/fast/unlimited connection you'd be better of looking for wired connection.